# Что значит директива RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-программирование

Что значит это - `RewriteCond` в Apache?

А конкретнее это это значит, если не трудно, разложите по полочкам, а то моему мозгу трудно воспринять эту информацию.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Что это значит? - Если запрашиваемая в URL директория или файл существуют обращаемся к ним напрямую документации

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Эти директивы задают условия для следующей после них директивы `RewriteRule`. Т.е. сами по себе они не применяются, после них должна идти директива, на которую они влияют

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php [L]
```

В частности `!-f` требует, чтобы правило `RewriteRule` применялось только в том случае, если запросу не соответствует физически существующий файл, а `!-d` - запрос не должен применяться, если запрашивается физически существующая папка. Таким образом, правило в `RewriteRule`, следующее за этими директивами будет касаться только виртуальных URL для которых нет папки или файла на диске сервера.

Comment: Идеально. Болшое прибольше Вам, спасибо! Это получается я таким образом защищу реальные пути месторасположения папок и файлов?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Это просто супер! Я именно это и искал.

Comment: Подстажите пожалуйста, я в .htaccess сделал эти правила, но физический файл всё равно могу открыть. `RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` , почему?  Я файл открываю где лежит .htaccess, а он находится в корне сайта

Comment: @gilo1212 Эти директивы не запрещают доступ к файлам, они лишь выводят их из под действия правила RewriteRule. Если вам нужно закрыть к ним доступ вероятно лучше создать еще один вопрос, посвященный этой проблеме.

Comment: Эти директивы не запрещают доступ к файлам, они лишь выводят их из под действия правила RewriteRule. - Это как? Чего то совсем я запутался.

Comment: Я пытаюсь в корен сайта открыть `http://mysite.com/package.json`, и сервер открыает его по этому адресу.  Там же в корне сайта у меня лежит `.htaccess`. В `.htaccess` прописанны правила - `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^index.php [L]`

Comment: Похоже я понял. Большое Вам  спасибо еще раз. У меня всё получилось!